# What is the logic error in this character counting code?

Tags: javascript, string, character

I am really at a standstill as to why this doesn't work as intended. It should output the number 4 for the amount of occurences of the letter s in the word Mississipi. I'm new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Liam

```js
function countCharacters(target, input) { //Defining of the function, the parameters are target and input
  var count = 0; //set count to 0 before the for loop
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + 1) { //the for loop that goes through each index of the input string
    if (input.indexOf(i) == target) { //if a character in the string matches the target character
      count = count + 1; //count adds 1 to its value
    }
  }
  console.log(count); //When it breaks out of the loop, the amount of times the target was matched will be printed
  return target, input; //return two parameters
}

console.log(countCharacters("s", "Mississippi"));
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Looks like the 'indexOf()' function expects a character and it tells you the location of the index where the character was found. But you are passing the index value itself. Try using 'charAt()', which I think is want you intended to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Array.indexOf()` to find the current character. Since `i` is the index of the current character, use it to take the current character from the string, and compare with the target. Return the `count` at the end.

Note: a `return` statement in JS can't return two items. If you you use a comma separated list - `target, input` for example - the last item would be returned.

```js
function countCharacters(target, input) {
  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (input[i] === target) { //if a character in the string matches the target character
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(countCharacters("s", "Mississippi"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing: you try to access letter through indexOf() - better to access it through the index, also function must return only one thing, yours instead returns two

```
function countCharacters(target, input) { 
  let count = 0; 
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
    if (input[i] === target) { 
      count++; 
    }
  } 
  return count;
}

console.log(countCharacters("s", "Mississippi"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing comparison with index and target. you should get current character then compare. as i did below it may help you...

```js
function countCharacters(target, input) { //Defining of the function, the parameters are target and input
  var count = 0; //set count to 0 before the for loop
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + 1) { //the for loop that goes through each index of the input string
    if (input[i] == target) { //if a character in the string matches the target character
      count = count + 1; //count adds 1 to its value
    }
  }
  console.log(count); //When it breaks out of the loop, the amount of times the target was matched will be printed
  return target, input; //return two parameters
}

console.log(countCharacters("s", "Mississippi"));
```